# Is there a way to make a c++ compiler flag as default

Tags: xcode, macos, bash, terminal, compiler-flags

Just like we specify input flags in the settings of the project in Xcode

Can I make few flags like -O3 or -fopenmp as default flags in command line when I use Terminal.
So that I dont have to type them everytime I compile some c++ fies. Is there a file in the installed gcc or C++ that I can edit to make them default.
Please let me know 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

For situations like this you'd probably use a makefile if it's project specific (or other similar automated build management like [scons](http://www.scons.org) or [cmake](http://www.cmake.org)).

If you want it always on the terminal, you can alias your command to always specify those options, i.e.

`alias g++='g++ -O3 -fopenmp'`

Note that you said 'terminal' so I assume this is a type of *nix. If that is the case you can also set this into your terminal profile, like `~/.bashrc` if you use bash, or `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh, etc.